# PHP ternary operator object assignment

Tags: php

I have an object:

```
$info = [
    'last_name' => $this->askForLastName(),
];
```

I am trying to read an environment variable in the form of env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', null) and trying to use the ternary operator so that it should only call the function if the env variable does not exist.

For instance:

```
$info = [
    'last_name' => env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', null)? env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', null) : $this->askForLastName(),
];
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: I guess that depends on what `env()` returns, could you share the function?

Comment: may be a precedence problem, use parentesis to try and be sure

Comment: So it works or doesn't work?  What's the result?

Comment: Does is work? It should. Since PHP 5.3 you can leave out the second sub-expression of the ternary operator (`?:`) if it's identical with the first one. i.e. `'last_name' => env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', null) ?: $this->askForLastName(),`.

Comment: Sure env will basically return the the environment variable from a text file and in the case it does not find it, it returns the second parameter

Comment: @LuisSiquot Precedence problem for what? There is only one operator in that expression.

Comment: I think you need to answer the question: "Does it or doesn't it work?"?

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not asking it right. I just wanted to make sure I wasnt doing anything wrong. @axiac thanks for the tip.

Comment: `env()` seems an undocumented function, not a variable. What does `env()` return when the variable does not exist? An error or a `falsy`?

Comment: The second parameter. @PaulH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work, but it can be improved.

For one, since there is no alternative case for the true clause, you can use the shorthand ternary operator.

`['last_name' => env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', NULL) ?: $this->askForLastName()']`;

Furthermore, while a null value will return false for an if clause, it's not very accurate or specific. If you want explicitly checking for null values, then use `is_null`. If you want null or false, use `empty`. In such a case, you will not be able to use the shorthand, as both the true / false clause must return a separate entity.

`['last_name' => is_null(env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', NULL)) ? $this->askForLastName() : env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', NULL)]`

You can take it a step further by getting rid of the multiple calls to env.

`['last_name' => is_null(($adminLastName = env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', NULL))) ? $this->askForLastName() : $adminLastName]`.

It is a matter of code style and preference. Just keep it consistent throughout your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use the [ternary operator shortcut](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

This way the `env()` function will be called just once (instead of twice):

```
$info = [
    'last_name' => env('ADMIN_LAST_NAME', null) ?: $this->askForLastName(),
];
```

It will work fine unless `''`, `null` or `false` are valid admin last names.